# How to add a banner through AdDuplex?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, adduplex

I've added adDuplex to my App,
i've done :

1- set ad unit name 
2- Add AdDuplex SDk

But one request i couldn't complete it,
which is "create a banner".I've made the app as template and target to the same app , but i cannot saving it .

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: please include your xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a banner in AdDuplex you first have to insert 4 lines of text ad and then press save. Saving will fail if these lines are empty.

Comment: I know what you mean,I think that was before as shown in their video..but now it changed , there are no 4 lines that you're talking about

Comment: @Judy, can you please check if 4 lines are visible in different browsers? What is your current browser's name and version?

Comment: I'm using  Firefox 37.0.2

Comment: @Judy and how about other browsers? 
P.S. Ad blocking plugins must be disabled when working in AdDuplex site.

Comment: Yes,that's right ..Thanks...I disabled the Ad blocker on my browser